# Why can't a numerical method solve an ODE that contains singularities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Consider the following 1st order IVP:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x} = 0,\hspace{10mm} y(0)=1$$

Can this even be solved through any numerical or analytical approximation methods?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense. The solutions to the equation are $\frac{C}{\ln(|x|)}$ and thus can only be defined for $x$ on intervals that don't include $-1,0$ or $1$. You could cook up a method that regularizes the problem by moving the starting point and then sends the starting point to 0, but the results will blow up as you change the starting point unless your method is really bad.

Comment: The IVP problem you mention doesn’t make sense. How can you define the value of $y$ at $0$ when you’re dividing by zero in the differential equation.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In general that's not totally true, because it's possible that the solutions to the equation have a removable discontinuity, so there is a natural way to define a generalized notion of solution. For a silly example, $(y'+y)/x=0,y(0)=1$ presumably has a solution of $e^{-x}$. But here the discontinuity is *not* removable.

Comment: Usually, in a numerical evaluation, we "remove" the singularities (change of variable, isolating divergences, etc... ) before we proceed to the numerical evaluation.